# Are unitary conformal field theories with central charge c>=1 realizable on the lattice?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, lattice-model

As John Cardy showed in 1986 in ["Operator content of two-dimensional conformally invariant theories"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321386905523), a conformal field theory (CFT) which is both unitary and has a finite number of primary operators must have a central charge $c<1$.

There are a number of critical lattice models that have a CFT continuum limit, e.g. the Ising and Potts model that both have $c<1$.
It should be impossible for a lattice model to represent an infinite number of (lattice representations of) primary operators, so does Cardy's result rule out *any* lattice model with unitary time evolution that has a $c \geq 1$ CFT continuum limit? The only possible loophole to this argument seems be a lattice model that represents a divergent number of primary operators in the continuum limit, does such a model exist?

Comment: I am not sure if such a lattice model exists, but one thing which is important for this discussion is that you can have finite number of primary fields for c > 1, if you extend your Chiral algebra from Virasoro to something else, like Superconformal algebra, W algebra or Affine algebra. In these cases you can have finitely many fields for c>1 - (https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9210010.pdf). Further, it is also possible to have a theory which has an extended chiral algebra to have a lattice realization, for example Tri-Critical Ising.